# Remove data from beginning of NSData object

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsrange

I am assembling a NSData object and I am getting the following

```
0100020000
```

This is what I want except for the leading zero.  I need it to be

```
100020000
```

I tried the following code. But it leaves me with 00020000.

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
[byteRequest replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:NULL length:0];
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question what the data actually looks like. Are those strings of hex bytes? text? If it's hex bytes, then each *pair* of digits represents a single byte, which means you're trying to remove just half of a byte off the front-- that's not going to work without a lot of additional bit-twiddling. But that would be a pretty unusual requirement so my guess is that you're actually after something different. Can you elaborate on what the data represents and what you need?

Comment: It is a string of hex bytes.  I figured out a better way to do it.  I was converting each piece to NSData and appending it.  If I convert the entire string to NSData instead it will fix my issue.  Additional zeros at the end will be fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, you have the following 5 bytes:

1, 0, 2, 0, 0

You are somehow converting that to hex, which creates two-digits per byte:

"01 00 02 00 00"

But this is just a textual representation of the previous bytes. It is equivalent to all of these:

"0100020000"

"0x0100020000"

"4,295,098,368" (in decimal)
"040000400000" (in octal)

And the one you appear to want: "100020000"

Just like "1.00" is equivalent to "1.0", "01" is equivalent to "1".

If your goal is to get a string of all the bytes as two-digit strings, except the first, which should only have as many digits as required, then here is an example of that:

```
 int bytes[5] = {1, 0, 2, 0, 0};
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x%02x%02x%02x%02x", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], bytes[4]];
```

You could use a loop and append these if the numbre of bytes is unknown. Start with `%x` and then use `%02x` for all the subsequent.